# Failed to detect set buildpack https://github.com/jasonswett/heroku-buildpack-nodejs

Tags: node.js, git, angular, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I bought the book angular for rails developers.

When delopying to Heroku I get a failed to detect set buildpack. I've included my package.json.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thx

---

Terminal error message when... $ git push heroku master

```
Writing objects: 100% (64/64), 15.94 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 64 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:

remote: -----> Failed to detect set buildpack     https://github.com/jasonswett/    heroku-buildpack-nodejs
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to still-harbor-34757.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/still-harbor-34757.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/still-harbor-34757.git'
```

---

my package.json

```
{
"name": "home-library",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"angular-cli": {},
"scripts": {
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
"lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
"test": "ng test",
"pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
"e2e": "protractor",
"heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.2.1",
"@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
"@angular/core": "2.2.1",
"@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
"@angular/http": "2.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
"@angular/router": "3.2.1",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
"zone.js": "^0.6.23",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
"@types/node": "^6.0.42",
"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.21",
"codelyzer": "~1.0.0-beta.3",
"jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
"karma": "1.2.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
"protractor": "4.0.9",
"ts-node": "1.2.1",
"tslint": "3.13.0",
"typescript": "~2.0.3",
"webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Heroku fail to detect Node.js buildpack?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38658038/4133798)

Comment: Have you tried [heroku buildpacks:clear](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39151605/199712)?

Comment: And from the project root, what is the output of `find . -name 'package.json'`? Is it `./client/package.json`? If it's not, that could be a problem.