# How to use heroku on a node react web app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, hosting

I tried to follow the official tuto but it doesn't works.

My project looks this:
my-app
  api
    package.json
  app
    package.json

Comment: can you list out the steps that you followed and what error you are recieving on the failing step.

Comment: I did heroku create, git add ., git commit -m 'initial', and git push heroku origin. The error is  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
   HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
   See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
 !     Push failed

Comment: I think this solution will help you.
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/43363309/6290298](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43363309/6290298)

Comment: define "doesn't work"? are you getting an error? did you define the proc file properly? is your buildpack well defined? are you not getting a buildpack detected when pushing? what does "heroku logs" show? it's very hard to help if you don't define your problem with more detail for the community to evaluate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If heroku is not detecting your buildpack, follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43363309/1042409).

If in other hand, your app is not running even if you defined your buildpack it might be because your proc file is not properly defined.

In your app, a file called `Procfile` must be created (with no extension) in the base of your directory. This file will tell heroku what to run.

A very simple example is this one. If for example your app has a server.js file, the procfile can be defined like this:

```
web: node server.js
```

If you have this file in your directory and you push to heroku, heroku will understand that it is a node app and will serve your app correctly.