# Heroku: “No default language could be detected for this app” error thrown for node app

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy my api on heroku using github but i get this message. I also tried heroku cli but i got the same error message.

[image: Heroku website error]

This is my package.json

[image: package.json]

This is my folder structure

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: It's gonna look for stuff like `/package.json`, but yours is in `/backend/package.json`. It doesn't know how to find that.

Comment: how do you suggest i do this? should i remove the backend folder or is there a way to tell it to look for the /backend/package.json directory...thanks

Comment: do check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362014/heroku-no-default-language-could-be-detected-for-this-app-error-thrown-for-no) link, if it answers the question

Comment: I checked that link and it didn't help.