# Error message when deploying a project to heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment

This is my first time deploying a project to Heroku and I keep getting an error message. I believe I've done everything right, but I'm missing one thing and I cant figure it out. Please help steer me in the right direction. It's saying a I need a buildpack. I'm not sure how to attain this.

Heres the error that I'm getting:

Build main **8026c781**
There was an issue deploying your app. View the build log for details.

-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
!     No default language could be detected for this app.
HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
!     Push failed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku: "No default language could be detected for this app" error thrown for node app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362014/heroku-no-default-language-could-be-detected-for-this-app-error-thrown-for-no)

Comment: Thank you. It helped to steer me in the right direction. I was using the incorrect buildpack, and I needed to add a php file to my project before I could deploy it.