# Fatal error when I run git heroku push master

Tags: git, heroku, fatal-error

I already run the following codes and everything went smoothly:

```
git init
git add .
git commit —m 'name'
heroku create
```

But when I run this code:

```
git push heroku master
```

I get this error:

```
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Please learn some Git basics before. Do you know what you are doing when you run those commands?

Comment: Though I didn't use Heroku, but I guess there is nothing like `git remote add` inside `heroku create`. Then the reference of "heroku" in `git push heroku master` is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33533834/6309), you need one more command before pushing:

```
cd /path/to/repo
heroku git:remote -a yourapp
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to do "heroku create" before git push heroku master