# App not compatible with buildpack - Heroku/python

Tags: python, github, heroku, buildpack

I get this message when trying to push my project to GitHub to connect with Heroku

```
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz

       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
       Push failed
```

I already put my `Requirements.txt` and `Procfile` in the root. My `Requirements.txt` looks like this:

```
json5==0.8.5
jsonschema==2.6.0
regex==2018.2.21
requests==2.23.0
schedule==0.6.0
spotipy==2.12.0
tweepy==3.8.0
```

and my `Procfile` looks like this:

```
  worker: python app.py
```

My GitHub repo is: https://github.com/dahliahadfury/Spotify-recommendation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I already put my `Requirements.txt` and `Procfile` in the root

Case is important. The requirements file must be named `requirements.txt` (all lowercase).

Rename your requirements file, commit, and deploy again:

- `git mv Requirements.txt requirements.txt`
- `git commit -m "Fix name of requirements file"`
- `git push heroku master`

Comment: hey thankyou for your help!
i did what you said but i got this message instead:
`fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`
is that mean heroku doesnt connect to my github repo?

Comment: hey thankyou so much for your help! it works now, i solve the problem above with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406721/heroku-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository thankyou again!

Comment: Yes, or if you're deploying via GitHub you can do that. I think a push to `master` on GitHub should automatically deploy in that case.